# Pass iteration variable from foreach to custom command

Tags: macros, conditionals, loops

I am trying to figure out why the following code does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\setProblemShow[2]{%
  \csdef{isProblemShow#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\getProblemShow[1]{%
  \csuse{isProblemShow#1}}

\begin{document}

    \setProblemShow{1}{1}

    \foreach \idx in {1,2,...,15} { \setProblemShow{\idx}{0} }

    \foreach \idx in {1,2,...,15} { Problem \idx \quad is \getProblemShow{\idx} \par }

\end{document}
```

It outputs

[image]

Why doesn't it call **\setProblemShow** properly whereas **\getProblemShow** seems to be called OK?

Comment: `\foreach` executes the code in a group, so none of the `\setProblemShow` executed in the first `\foreach` has effects when the loop ends.

Comment: @egreg I don'T understand. But why it works in the second `\foreach`?

Comment: I don't see it working, do you?

Comment: @egreg Well, it produces the above output. It seems working to me.

Comment: I see no number after the first (which is due to `\setProblemShow{1}{1}` outside the loop). I think you would expect “Problem 2 is 0”.

Comment: @egreg Of course. None of the variables were assigned except for the first one which I assigned outside the first `\foreach`. But the second `\foreach` outputs 1's correctly for those variables which were assigned. Yes, I'd expect zeros elsewhere, but the first loop does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\foreach` executes every cycle in a group; so when you do the first cycle in the first `\foreach`, what's actually done is

```
\begingroup
\csdef{isProblemShow1}{0}
\endgroup
```

and the definition is forgotten as soon as `\endgroup` is executed.

In the second loop you do

```
\begingroup
Problem 1\quad is \csuse{isProblemShow1} \par
\endgroup
\begingroup
Problem 2\quad is \csuse{isProblemShow2} \par
\endgroup
```

and so on. The first one produces

> Problem 1 is 1

because of the outer `\setProblemShow{1}{1}`; the second one produces

> Problem 2 is

because `\csuse{isProblemShow2}` simply does `\relax`, because the token resulting from `\csname isProblemShow2\endcsname` is undefined.

If you make global definitions in the first loop, you get 0 in every line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\setProblemShow[2]{%
  \global\csdef{isProblemShow#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\getProblemShow[1]{%
  \csuse{isProblemShow#1}}

\begin{document}

    \setProblemShow{1}{1}

    \foreach \idx in {1,2,...,15} { \setProblemShow{\idx}{0} }

    \foreach \idx in {1,2,...,15} { Problem \idx \quad is \getProblemShow{\idx} \par }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\csgdef` instead of `\global\csdef`.

Comment: @Manuel I suspected it existed, but was lazy. ;-)

Comment: I think it's pretty complete. It doesn't have `\glet`, `\csglet`, `\gletcs` nor `\csgletcs`, though.